# Spring / web.xml

Tags: spring

I am doing my first web MVC spring project with
java class configuration. I have eclipse as IDE 
and I configured a project to detect those configuration classes. I have deleted a web.xml file. I use Tomcat 7 as deployment server.

I notice following problem :

When I restart my server time to time (can't figure when exactly) Eclipse adds a web.xml file to my WEB-INF folder what causes a problem  when I try to run this project. I have to delete web.xml file than clean project and server and then click run -> run on a server and is fine till next time.

Any idea how to block adding web.xml file by IDE?

**Problem solved:**

Properties -> Project facets -> Dynamic Web module version changed to 3.0

Comment: I recommend using Spring Boot for new projects instead of messing with an external container.

Comment: The version of the "dynamic web project" in eclipse is probably wrong, and Eclipse thus thinks it needs a web.xml file.Set it to 3.0 at least.

Comment: @JBNizet How to set version ?

Comment: Project - Properties - Project Facets - Dynamic Web Module: change the version